# Placeholder cannot find array of data in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have this stack trace:

Could not resolve placeholder 'aa.bb' in value "${aa/bb}"

My Java:

```
 @Value("${aa.bb}")List<String>  bb
```

application.yml: (YES, the number of space is good)

```
aa:
   bb: 
    - XX
    - YY
```

fun fact:

```
 @Value("${aa.bb[1]}")
```

return me 'YY'

Comment: ``\$`` is not valid Java.

Comment: you might want to use `@ConfigurationProperties('aa')` in your config class and `List<String> bb` field in there

Comment: Are you on a filesystem that only supports 3 character filename extensions? If not you should conider applying the [recommended file extension `.yaml`](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for your YAML files

Answer (score 0):

YAML uses **indentation** with one or more spaces to describe nested collections. Your `XX` and `YY` values are incorrectly indented.

```
aa:
  bb: 
    - XX
    - YY
```

See [The YAML Format - Collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections) documentation for detail.